# HMEventTrigger set enable fires error

Tags: ios, simulation, homekit

I got this error message, when I'd like to set enable=TRUE a HMEventTrigger on simulator
message:
Error Domain=HMErrorDomain Code=84 "Location Services for HomeKit is disabled." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Location Services for HomeKit is disabled.}

I can NOT find any solution to this problem!
Can any one suggest something?

Comment: I think you are adding the HMLocationEvent. So first you have to enable the location services

Comment: Let me know if you have any issues

Comment: no, that was the problem-I think-that the characteristic was not notable

Comment: If possible paste some code which you are trying